# class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbck not found

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I want to implemenet Firebase to my aplication.

Firebase just for reset password.

I had this problem and I do not have any idea how to solve that.

> error: cannot access zzbck
>
> class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbck not found

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'

}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven{
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user_pc.glavnastranicaprojekat"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    multiDexEnabled = true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:1.0.3'

implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'

implementation 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'



}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I hope someone have solution for that problem

Comment: Why do you need `com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0`?

Comment: @DougStevenson I need it for other part in my app

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use google play services libraries, then do not use the combined play-services target.

> Note: Don't use the combined play-services target. It brings in dozens of libraries, bloating your application. Instead, specify only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses.

You need to use individual APIs, example:

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'
```

Also use the latest versions, more info here:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: I want to use libraries for google maps and now for firebase. It can be done?

Comment: use this `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1` and firebase libraries

Comment: clean and rebuild the project

Answer (score 0):

This may be late but for someone facing the same error, go to your app gradle file and update your play-services-vision to the newest version of the time. This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I know this will be late for you
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RB3YcwNUeITA073SPwerCcx_GetI4Jp_

1. download the google-play-service.jar to a folder inside your
   application  and extract it there
2. in android studio right click on
   the jar file and click on add as a library

Comment: Please don't recommend third party sites to download jars. Use an official link instead.

Comment: actualy this was in an old project in my computer so i couldn't find any other site @Zoe